# Cracking of pages

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I have noticed that after using a book for some time, a few pages develop small cracks on them. What is the science behind it and can it really damage a book? Basically, something like this:

[image]

And, if damaged, what can be the extent of the damage caused?

P.S: The paper in this photograph is of 60 to 70 GSM standard.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95200/discussion-on-question-by-shishir-maharana-cracking-of-pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things affect paper for the propensity to crack like your image:

1. the quality of the paper as supplied - if it has defects in it then they will get worse over time,
2. the humidity - paper will absorb humidity, but if too dry it cracks, if too wet it falls apart. So, keeping it within range prolongs the life.

What you show looks like a manufacturing defect or it was creased during the book manufacturing process, if this is handled roughly, then it will get worse over time. It could, of course, be down to rough handling by a third party when they opened the book.

Comment: No, personally, I don't think that it is a manufacturing defect because it was not on the pages when I first read it. Like I said It has developed over time.